# preg_match to get div contents

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to get the contents of a div named: `<img id="hplogo-img" src="thelinkiwant"/>`

I have this code which isn't working, it just echo's 'Array':

```
<?php 
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html($url); 
preg_match('/<img id= \'hplogo-img\'>(.*)<\/div>/s',$html,$matches);
echo $matches;
?>
```

If it's possible to do this with straight PHP that would be preferred. Any idea's why I can't get the link from the div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the method the parser provide.

```
$ret = $html->find('img[id=hplogo-img]');
```

Answer (score 2):

$matches is an array.

Try using

```
print_r($matches)
```

You should see the arrays content :)

The first element should be what you're looking for. So make:

```
echo $matches[0];
```